# Why don't intent locks conflict with lower level locks in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, concurrency

I'm reading "SQL Server fundamentals" and don't understand why if I have an intent lock on a table, I can still have exclusive or shared locks on it's sub-parts. Can someone explain?

I mean we lock an entire table and don't want it to be modified, but here comes an exclusive lock and modifies this table's row. I obviously don't understand something, so, please explain to me how this thing works, thanks!

Below is the table that the author provides in his book.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100789/sql-server-locks-explained

Comment: Compatibility matrix:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we modify rows in a table, we can't modify the same rows by other transactions, and non-intent locks guarantee that.

However, an intent lock on a table is compatible with an exclusive lock on parts of a table because the purpose of an intent lock is to protect modifications that modify *all of data*.

One example would be when you are reading rows of table A, so you have shared locks on those rows and an intent shared lock on that table, intent shared lock protects from a situation where another transaction can obtain an exclusive lock on that table A and try to delete it(that is a modification of *all of data*). Since the shared locks on rows were first to start reading rows' data, it is logical to allow that operation to finish first.